# Map Integration in Unity3d

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, maps, unity-game-engine

I am going to make Geocaching app in unity. As you know that this sort of app have very detail use of maps. So is this possible that i can use unity3d to make this app without using External plugin. I want to make this app for both iPhone and Android. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to use Open Street Map's tiles inside of Unity 3D.

This project hasn't been updated in a while but it should be a good starting point: 
https://bitbucket.org/darktable/unity3d-open-street-map

Comment: Hi I tried download above above project but it says you don't have  access to this repo ?